# Factor the expression completely.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(a^{ 2 }+1)^{ 2 }-7(a^{ 2 }+1)+10$$

So far I got:

$$(a^{ 2 }+1)(a^2+1)-7a^{ 2 }+3$$

I feel like I am going about this the wrong way. I need a push in the right direction.

Comment: To begin, let $y=a^2+1$. We want to factor $y^2-7y+10$. Then replace $y$ by $a^2+1$ in the factors, and see whether you can factor further.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas, Sorry, if I stepped on your toes.

Comment: "I feel like I am going about this the wrong way." Yes, this is the wrong way. You want to factor the whole expression, not just part of it. And since $a^2+1$ is not a factor of the original expression, it is not clear that your attempt is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(STRONG) HINT:  You have a quadratic $x^2-7x+10$ in the variable $x=a^2+1$.  Find x first using the quadratic formula and then solve for a using the equation $x=a^2+1$.  This will give you the factors.

Comment: $$(a+1)(a-1)$$?

Comment: No, I don't see how that fits into the problem.

Comment: Solve? There is no equation. I think you mean *factor* $x^2-7x+10$, or find the roots of $x^2-7x+10$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, Isn't it clear?  Perhaps it is clearer now.

Comment: "Find $x$ first" implies there is an equation here. There is no equation. You are not trying to solve anything, you are trying to factor.

Comment: I apologize for the late response. This makes a lot more sense once I read the bit about equations of the quadratic type in my textbook.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a^{ 2 }+1)^{ 2 }-7(a^{ 2 }+1)+10$$

put x=$a^{2}$,then we get

$$\implies \ (x+1)^{2}-7(x+1)+10$$
Now solve this

$$\implies\ x^2+2x+1-7x-7+10$$
$$\implies\ x^2-5x+4$$
$$\implies \ (x-4)(x-1)$$

i.e $$\implies\ (a^{2}-4)(a^{2}-1)$$
therefore four roots of the equation are: $$a=+2,-2,+1,-1$$

Comment: Not looking for roots, just factorization.

Comment: Ok then last step is ur factorization result $$(a^2-4)(a^2-1)$$                                                    it is what u wanted right?

Comment: Or if you want, you can directly factorize the given initial statement also...it's factors are -5 and -2

Answer (score 1):

$$(a^2+1)^2-7(a^2+1)+10$$
$x=a^2+1$
$$x^2-7x+10=x^2-5x-2x+10=x(x-5)-2(x-5)=(x-2)(x-5)=$$
then
$$(a^2+1)^2-7(a^2+1)+10=(a^2+1-2)(a^2+1-5)=(a^2-1)(a^2-4)=$$
$$=(a-1)(a+1)(a+2)(a-2)$$